# Union type mismaching typescript Repository<R> | Repository<V> is not assignable to type Repository<V>

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, union-types

I have a class:

```
export abstract class RepositoryPaginationSwitcher<R, V> {
  business(businessType: BusinessType): Repository<R> | Repository<V>;
  business(
    businessType: BusinessType,
    paginate?: boolean,
  ): RepositoryAndPagination<R> | RepositoryAndPagination<V>;
  business(
    businessType: BusinessType,
    paginate?: boolean,
  ):
    | (RepositoryAndPagination<R> | RepositoryAndPagination<V>)
    | (Repository<R> | Repository<V>) {
    const repository = super.business(businessType);
    if (!paginate) {
      return repository;
    }
    const segment = businessToSegmentMap.get(businessType);
    const pagination = this.getPagination()[segment];

    return {
      repository,
      pagination,
    };
  }

}
```

where

```
// library types
export interface ObjectLiteral { [key: string]: any; }
type Repository<T extends ObjectLiteral> = { obj: T; }
type PaginateConfig<T> = { columns: { [Key in keyof T]: boolean }; }
// my types
enum BusinessType {
    REALTY = 'REALTY',
    VEHICLE = 'VEHICLE'
}
export type RepositoryAndPagination<E> = {
    repository: Repository<E>;
    pagination: PaginateConfig<E>;
};
declare function getRepo<R, V>(
  businessType: BusinessType
): Repository<R> | Repository<V>;

declare function getPagination<R, V>(
  businessType: BusinessType
): PaginateConfig<R> | PaginateConfig<V>;
```

And i have the following error in the return statement:

```
libs/core/src/common/base/repository-pagination-switcher.ts:41:7 - error TS2322: Type 'Repository<R> | Repository<V>' is not assignable to type 'Repository<V>'.
  Type 'Repository<R>' is not assignable to type 'Repository<V>'.
    Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
      Type 'EntityTarget<R>' is not assignable to type 'EntityTarget<V>'.
        Type 'EntitySchema<R>' is not assignable to type 'EntityTarget<V>'.
          Type 'EntitySchema<R>' is not assignable to type 'EntitySchema<V>'.
            The types of 'options.columns' are incompatible between these types.
              Type '{ [P in keyof R]?: EntitySchemaColumnOptions; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof V]?: EntitySchemaColumnOptions; }'.
                Type 'keyof V' is not assignable to type 'keyof R'.
                  Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'keyof R'.
                    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof R'.

41       repository,
         ~~~~~~~~~~

libs/core/src/common/base/repository-pagination-switcher.ts:42:7 - error TS2322: Type 'PaginateConfig<R> | PaginateConfig<V>' is not assignable to type 'PaginateConfig<V>'.
  Type 'PaginateConfig<R>' is not assignable to type 'PaginateConfig<V>'.
    Types of property 'relations' are incompatible.
      Type 'Extract<R extends Record<string, any> ? { [K in keyof R]-?: K extends string ? R[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : R[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<K, U extends Record<...> ? { [K in keyof U]-?: K extends string ? U[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : U[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<...> : `${K}` | Join<...> : neve...' is not assignable to type 'Extract<V extends Record<string, any> ? { [K in keyof V]-?: K extends string ? V[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : V[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<K, U extends Record<...> ? { [K in keyof U]-?: K extends string ? U[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : U[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<...> : `${K}` | Join<...> : neve...'.
        Type 'Extract<R extends Record<string, any> ? { [K in keyof R]-?: K extends string ? R[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : R[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<K, U extends Record<...> ? { [K in keyof U]-?: K extends string ? U[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : U[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<...> : `${K}` | Join<...> : neve...' is not assignable to type 'Extract<V extends Record<string, any> ? { [K in keyof V]-?: K extends string ? V[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : V[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<K, U extends Record<...> ? { [K in keyof U]-?: K extends string ? U[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : U[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<...> : `${K}` | Join<...> : neve...'.
          Type '{ [K in R extends Record<string, any> ? { [K in keyof R]-?: K extends string ? R[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : R[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<K, U extends Record<...> ? { [K in keyof U]-?: K extends string ? U[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : U[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<...> : `${K}` | Join<...> : neve...' is not assignable to type 'Extract<V extends Record<string, any> ? { [K in keyof V]-?: K extends string ? V[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : V[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<K, U extends Record<...> ? { [K in keyof U]-?: K extends string ? U[K] extends Date ? `${K}` : U[K] extends (infer U)[] ? `${K}` | Join<...> : `${K}` | Join<...> : neve...'.

42       pagination,
         ~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm struggling to tell typescript that the repository and the pagination can be respectively of the types Repository<R> or Repository<V> and PaginateConfig<R> or PaginateConfig<V>. What I'm doing wrong?

I tried to change de typing to RepositoryAndPagination<R | V> and another error occurred.

EDIT:
Minimum reproductive code:
[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false&strictNullChecks=false&strictFunctionTypes=false&strictPropertyInitialization=false&strictBindCallApply=false&noImplicitThis=false&noImplicitReturns=false&alwaysStrict=false#code/PTAEBsEsCMCcENYE9QBckAcCmBnAUHlgB4YD2sqokAdqlrAGbwDGWoA8tAFZbOoAykOgnCgA3nlBTQAbQDWWJAC5QOVLBoBzALor41JAG48AXwLpsoAEpYyOIeSQAeACqhidagBMcHbrwEhenhwAD5QAF5xSWlSbhUXYzM8CzYABXhNGng6AGFSagZITVdwqIlpUGZScABXAFtqHBUKyukZAGlFKmpQBSRSBlAXXVBoUhqsfVAYqRMkghBQepRU-CxqBtAAIVr7alwcF0w2VqkrAFEAQX4XAE1I0AByS5v7p4AaWdAANQuACQAkrl+BdHk8-kCQRcnqYCMQyBQ0CdrLZSPZUI4rt4MllqDlIAUnBcytEpLA0RjHCobHYHMhiaFjFIMJlsqhCdQVLj2Vh8oVioyksY8AxatQ+JzQJosKhaaQnFYPr9QgAKaB7GiHY7YFS7fbak4AShplPpzis4QAPqi6ZiGT9wmJQEt6qRmAovKAxRKOQVvhTULVYL0zm04lwWiZQPBfPokN95gQzD7JQVpbKefi-dRFcrHerNQccEcTnqi4bsCbQFmcnyCkUSpbQDba3kG4LHeIXWA3R6sF7UzmA7Lg6HvpVqnVGs1xNHYzGDImRclmOBY74XLhULl1yW8yrot8NQaS4XT6XdTsKyWdVhq-KqQzmzbH+anI7mdIT1qzxPvzel5YOWF53l8bTSKyeJ1gA-Co4yTPo4HSA+Zr2kg2JeG2nKKtatrouamHYUSn7HoBqr-lIP7FkBIG-kByEQVBvJwWMEzgFM1CMaAJrfDaqpvuhRFstmOEvvhT4YTiIkEiRoRGnxoACWhji4S2Envo6RpktI1RNJQFJ2o4jwynKaIHgW1GVveX5SJAQyqgAhMx2b3jplSBmOoCGQR6G2aAZiTgUaigC5sm9FEpnEbmSoque9F3kaIoeaOIbudIPmSdxLIyTm3FJnMphAA)

Comment: When I paste that in my IDE I get a lot of errors unrelated to your question.  Please consider [edit]ing the code to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WK92DN).

Comment: Edited with playground link @jcalz

Comment: You're already doing unsafe things (• there's no way to safely implement `getRepo()` or `getPagination()` since they return values dependent on `R` and `V` without taking any parameters dependent on them • you're using overloads so the body is checked loosely against the call signatures) so I'd suggest just using a type assertion and moving on, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N72RBw).    Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?